# Android - Does an ImageView resizes the image (and doesn't save the original)?

Tags: android, image, memory, resize, imageview

Quite a simple questions, can't find an answer..

I'm asking in order to know if even though the ImageView shows a smaller version of the original image - does it still use the full memory size of the original .. ?
(I refer to an image which was loaded from the SD-card and not from resources)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will use the original size. You have to resize all your bitmaps before assign then to an ImageView, otherwise you will have a lot of problems with **Out Of Memory Error**.

You should also calculate the final size of you ImageView and resize the Bitmap.

Some code to get you going.

```
private static Bitmap createBitmap(@NonNull String filePath, int width )
{
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath , options );

    // Getting original image properties
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;


    int scale       = -1;
    if ( imageWidth < imageHeight ) {
        scale   = Math.round( imageHeight / width );
    } else {
        scale   = Math.round(imageWidth / width);
    }
    if ( scale <= 0 )
        scale = 1;

    options.inSampleSize    = scale;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds  = false;

    // Create a resized bitmap
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath , options);
    return scaledBitmap;
}
```

You should also consider:

- Maintain all Bitmap operations outside the main Thread.
- Handle Concurrency correctly
- Make use of some open source lib, like this [one](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)